# What's my real Tor ip, torsocks?

Tags: configuration, torsocks, ip-address

I'm on ubuntu-mate 18.04.

I use Torsocks v2.2.0 in my terminal and applet.

i use `wget http://checkip.dyndns.org/ -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1`

witch send me my public IP.

I also use Tor proxy for whole system.

To see my IP at every moment i use the applet "indicator-ip" witch show public ip at every moment in the menu-bar.

my issue is that torsocks shows public IP with

`wget http://checkip.dyndns.org/ -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1`

And when i check on `https://check.torproject.org/?lang=fr` or `https://whatismyipaddress.com/` it shows me another IP.

Sometimes it takes times to get the same IP adress, but sometimes it never changes to the same IP adress.

I'm also need to `service tor restart` at startup (1s after restart) with script because if not my web pages need a reload and with this script sometimes

Anyone understand what i tryed to explain can let an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use torify, a tool that comes with the `tor` package.

`torify wget http://checkip.dyndns.org/ -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d: -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1`

Answer (score 0):

that is anonymity feature

a semi random exit node is chosen for each domain

checkip.dyndns.org check.torproject.org whatismyipaddress.com different domains

the exit node changes every so often